Type not found for classes made in other files with shared package
I am making a small program for school similar to snake, and we are told to make a separate code file for every class, or every one complete thing I guess, so I so far have 3 classes where the third class wants to use the other two classes types as parameters, but I just get not found: Type "name".
These are my three files, the first one is for moving coordinates, the second is for chosing which keys are used to move the snake (we are supposed to have 2 different ones out at the same time, like a two-player game, so they need different controls, usually awsd and arrows). The third class is the snake, or mole, itself which needs to have a position, of the type we made the first class, and a set of keys that moves it, the second class.
package blockbattle

case class Pos(x:Int, y:Int):
    def moved(delta: (Int, Int)): Pos = Pos(x + delta(0), y + (delta(1)))

package blockbattle

case class KeyControl(left: String, right: String, up:String, down:String):
    def direction(key:String): (Int, Int) = 
        if key==left then
            (-1,0)
        else if key==right then
            (1,0)
        else if key==up then
            (0, -1)
        else if key==down then
            (0, 1)
        else (0, 0)

package blockbattle

class Mole(val name: String,
var pos: Pos,
var dir: (Int, Int),
val color: java.awt.Color, 
val keyControl: KeyControl
):

I think I'm using packages wrong, because I don't get type not found if I just copy paste one of the classes into the same file, but I'm told this should work (using classes, not this exact example)
Screenshot of the issue, using VSCode with metals:


Where are you using the class "Mole"? I only see the definition but not the declaration in which the error is being raised

You've already asked this question and we already asked for more details that you still don't provide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79078563/type-not-found-when-using-classes-from-other-files-with-the-same-package-scala . Specifically: how are you running/compiling your code?

Not sure I understand the question, I'm writing the code in vscode with metals.

I get the type not found error in the parameters of mole, "var pos: Pos" and "val keyControl:KeyControl" both give me "not found:Type"

Maybe a screenshot would help. I guess something is wrong with your VSCode/Metals setup.

@simonforslund I meant: how are your files organized? My first bet would be they're in an unexpected folder.

@simonforslund do you have import statements on the three different files? What are the names of the three files?

@Jaime Caffarel the names of the files are the same as the classes in them, do I need to import the package as well? How do I import the package in that case

Nevermind. Didn't realize that the files are all on the same package, so the imports are not necessary here

@simonforslund are you using a build tool like sbt, scala-cli, mill? Or nothing? If so, metals can't work and that is why you get an error. If you are indeed using a build tool, can you share the configuration of those tools? Can you share your directory structure?

Scala compiler needs to know about all the code in order to correctly compile and link things.
You can just put your Scala files in a directory. Let's assume scala-code. Then just go to that directory using cd scala-code.
I am assuming that you have another file called Runner.scala which contains the main method where you are using these classes. And it looks something like following,
package blockbattle

object Runner:
  def main(args: Array[String]):
    // some code using your other classes

Now you can compile your code using.
scalac *.scala

This will create another directory named blockbattle which will contain the compiled scala classes.
Now you can run your code using,
scala blockbattle.Runner


Similarly, when you are working with an IDE like vscode + metals, it needs to know the files to properly compile and link them. We use build tools for that. Popular build tools for Scala are sbt, maven and mill.
Here is how you use sbt with vscode+metals.
Create a directoy for your project (for example my-scala-project).
Put your scala files under my-scala-project/src/main/scala/blockbattle.
Now create another file called my-scala-project/build.sbt with following content.

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.5.1" // whichever scala version you want

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "my-scala-project"
  )

Now... open the folder my-scala-project using vscode. metals should detect it as a sbt project and compile things correctly.
